# Todo notes inside minted

Tags: minted, code, todonotes, annotations

I'm trying to use Todonotes inside minted in order to easily annotate some code. I tried using escapeinside but the following code results in 5 errors unfortunately.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{todonotes}

\begin{document}

\begin{minted}[breaklines, linenos, fontfamily=courier, fontsize=\footnotesize, escapeinside=||]{sql}
Code
|\todo{Hello}|
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `|\todo[inline]{Hello}|` spares you from errors but I am also not sure if the output is what one should expect.